# Unable to cast object type 'PictureBox' to myClassControl

Tags: c#, casting, controls

I have a class that extends to `Control`:

```
public foo : Control 
{
  //.. 
}
```

And then I get a control:

```
var baa = (((foo)((Control)Controls.Find(controlName, true).First()));
baa.etc = ..;
```

But when I do:

```
 ((PictureBox)((Control)controlImg)).MyExtensionMethod(..)
```

I get an **exception**:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' to type 'ControlExtensions.foo'.

How to fix this exception and let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: foo extends Control. PictureBox extends Control. That's where the commonality ends. A dog is an animal. A cat is an animal. Try casting a dog into a cat. See how that turns out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to fix this. You class `foo` is correct. The error message explains it all. `foo` does not inherit `PictureBox`. If `foo` is a picture box of some sort, implement the `PictureBox` class and not `Control`.

To give you a real life example:

```
interface IAnimal { }
class Dog : IAnimal { public static void Bark() { } }
class Cat : IAnimal { public static void Meow() { } }
```

The signature of `Cat` is different than `Dog` as `Cat` defines `Cat.Meow()`, whereas `Dog` does not. `Dog` defines `Dog.Bark()`, whereas `Cat` does not. For example, the following code with comments will help you wrap your head around this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dog myDog = new Dog(); // myDog contains definition for Bark
        IAnimal myPet = (IAnimal)myDog; // Cast not necessary.
                                        // myPet's signiature is of Dog, but typeof(myPet)
                                        //   is Animal as it was boxed (google for help on this)
        Cat myCat = (Cat)myPet // now try and imagine this in real life
                               // (turning a dog into a cat) [I don't even]
                               // It doesn't work because Cat doesn't
                               //   contain a definition for Bark()
        Cat myDimentedCat = (Cat)(IAnimal)myDog; // which is why this code fails.
    }
}
```

---

What I am trying to show is the same thing as `a square is a rectangle, but a rectangle isn't always a square`:

```
interface IRectangle { }
interface ISquare : IRectangle { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both Anthony in the comment and Cole in his answer showed you where the exception come from. As to how fix it, I'm not sure if I got exactly what you intend to do, but looking at the name of the method you are trying to call, and at the fact that you say that foo "extends" Control,  it seems to me that you are trying to extend the behaviour of windows form controls adding some MyExtensionMethod. If this is the case, you should not create a foo class derived from Control, but a static class containing the extension methods you need. I.e. your code should look like this:

```
public static class SomeControlExtensions
{
    public static int MyExtensionMethod(this Control aCtl)
    {
        // whatever you want
    }
}
```

An extension method has always at least an argument that represent the receiver of the message. This is identified by the keyword "this" before the type of the argument. In this way you will be able to compile this:

```
Control baa = (Control)Controls.Find(controlName, true).First();
baa.MyExtensionMethod();
```